how to optimize TypeConverter BoilerPlate code
I have a Data Class with val of type "List of another Data Class".
data class AddressBook{
   val persons: List<Person>
   val addressList: List<Address>
}

I have created a converter class. But this creates boilerplate as we have to create the same @TypeConverter fun if we have more of such a list
So, I created a generic
class DataListConverter<T> {
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromList(list: List<T>): String {
        val gson = Gson()
        return gson.toJson(list)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun toList(data: String): List<T> {
        val listType = object : TypeToken<List<T>>() {}.type
        return Gson().fromJson(data, listType)
    }
}

Now @TypeConverters(DataListConverter::class) will not work as this will not accept generic as it can't parse the Type @ run time.
Any help would be appreciated. (Doing this for learning purposes) (edited)

This isn't really the relational database way of doing things. Instead of storing a json string you should have a separate table to represent the associated data. See the Android Developer docs

@TrentMeyer thanks for your msg. I have implemented the way you've mentioned. But I wanted to see how this works as json

Your code doesn't work because Java's generics are erased at runtime due to type erasure, so the actual type of T is unknown, and TypeToken<List<T>> can't resolve the type.
Try this, because it uses Class<T>, which provides the actual class of T at runtime. By using TypeToken.getParameterized(List::class.java, clazz).type, List<T> is correctly resolved and can be used with Gson.
class DataListConverter<T>(
    private val cls: Class<T>
) {
    private val g = Gson()

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromList(list: List<T>?): String {
        return g.toJson(list)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun toList(data: String?): List<T>? {
        if (data == null) return emptyList()
        val type = TypeToken.getParameterized(List::class.java, cls).type
        return g.fromJson(data, type)
    }
}


val personConverter = DataListConverter(Person::class.java)
val adressConverter = DataListConverter(Adress::class.java)


Thanks for your time on this. Faruk this again won't help me. @TypeConverters(DataListConverter(Person::class.java)::class) is not possible

I didn't understand what you mean by @TypeConverters(DataListConverter(Person::class.java)::class). Annotations don't accept generic types, they work at compile time, while generic type information is only available at runtime. So, you can't pass a generic type to @TypeConverters.

Exactly. So as of now no option other than adding the hardcoded same kind of methods with @TypeConverter for Persons and AddressList
